# Remove many elements from a list python

Tags: python, list

So I'm coding a basic chess game and I already created a function to calculate all the movements a piece can make (with all, I mean even negative numbers, current position and numbers > 7), **every possible position is saved as a tuple inside a list, but how can I delete positions off of the board from my list?**
First I tried with:

```
for i in movements:
        if (i == piece[1]) or (i[0] < 0) or (i[0] > 7) or (i[1] < 0) or (i[1] > 7): #Where piece[1] is the current position
            movements.remove(i)
```

Then I read in other posts that *I shouldn't modify a list while iterating it*, instead list comprehension was recommended, and I wrote this.

```
movements = [i for i in movements if not (i == piece[1]) or (i[0] < 0) or (i[0] > 7) or (i[1] < 0) or (i[1] > 7)]
```

This solution kind of works but still some "random" positions are thrown and I don't know why.

I also thought on creating a list of elements that I don't want and then remove one by one from the original list, but I don't think it's a good way to do it.

Am I doing something wrong? Or how can I solve this task?
Thanks!

Comment: The list comprehension is the way to go, but I’m not sure you have inverted your condition.

Comment: Well, I tried it without the "not" and returns positions off of the board, but still it has a weird behavior.

Comment: As written, `not` only applies to `(i == piece[1])`, rather than the other conditions. You could put `not` in front of each condition, but then you must replace `or`s with `and`s (de Morgan's law). Or you can put parentheses around the whole thing before using `not`. Or you could make a separate function to define whether the `i` value is valid, so that the line of code is not so confusing.

Comment: Yes, I guess I forgot about the big parentheses, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get cleaner, more easily understood code - and get it right the first time - by separating out smaller pieces of the logic and giving them useful names.

The "inner" logic is that of deciding whether a given move is valid - notice the technique for inverting the condition: I negate each part and then also swap `and` and `or` (due to [de Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)). Alternately, I just think about how I would have written the "valid" condition directly, rather than negating the "invalid" condition.

```
def is_valid(move, piece):
    return (move != piece[1]) and (i[0] >= 0) and (i[0] <= 7) and (i[1] >= 0) and (i[1] <= 7)
```

We can take advantage of Python's special behaviour for chained comparison operators to make this even easier to read:

```
def is_valid(move, piece):
    return (move != piece[1]) and (0 <= i[0] <= 7) and (0 <= i[1] <= 7)
```

Then, the "outer" logic is applying this test to each element of the original move list and assigning the result back:

```
moves = [move for move in moves if is_valid(move, piece)]
```

Comment: It works! And you're right it's way easier thinking on the "valid" condition, also I didn't know the chained comparison operators technique, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```py
movements = [i for i in movements if not ((i == piece[1]) or (i[0] < 0) or (i[0] > 7) or (i[1] < 0) or (i[1] > 7) )]
```